# BBEdit GREP Find Replace

Tags: replace, find, line, bbedit

I'm working with a tab-delimited file in BBEdit. The file looks like this:

```
00:15:50;11     text1     text2
00:35:17;03     text4     text5
00:35:20;03     text6   
00:35:20;22     text7
```

Basically, it has:
Timecode  Tab  Text  Tab  Text  Etc

I want to take the second line of timecode and add it after the first line. I want it to look like this:

```
00:15:50;11     00:35:17;03     text1     text2
00:35:17;03     00:35:20;03     text4     text5
00:35:20;03     00:35:20;22     text6
00:35:20;22     text7
```

I've tried using this piece of GREP code:

FIND:

```
`(?-m)([0-9][0-9][; :][0-9][0-9][; :][0-9][0-9][; :][0-9][0-9])(.*)\r([0-9][0-9][; :][0-9][0-9][; :][0-9][0-9][; :][0-9][0-9])`
```

REPLACE:

```
'\1\t\3\2\r\3'
```

My problem is that it only searches and replaces every other line. If I do a find/replace all, it looks like this:

```
00:15:50;11     00:35:17;03     text1     text2
00:35:17;03     text4     text5
00:35:20;03     00:35:20;22     text6
00:35:20;22     text7
```

It's skipping every other line. I want to do a search/replace all in several hundred files. I'm wondering if there's something that I can change to make sure it gets every single line.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I took your regex and modified it slightly.

The trick is to not match the Timecode at the beginning of the line. So, use [Positive Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(?<=([0-9][0-9][; :][0-9][0-9][; :][0-9][0-9][; :][0-9][0-9]))  /*lookbehind to see if timecode exists, but dont match. 
                                                                But, the use of parenthesis makes it the first capture group.*/
(.*)
\r
([0-9][0-9][; :][0-9][0-9][; :][0-9][0-9][; :][0-9][0-9])
```

Before,

[image]

After,

[image]